# php GET and generate with arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Quick overview: trying to build a gallery with a string from `$_GET` ('foo'), which was passed via AJAX and then generate a small list from that, with title and description.

Is it possible for an array to have 3 elements? In the `foreach` here it generates `list items` that use 'foo', and then a title and description follow, but I don't know how to pick out the proper/associated title/description, the one that relates to 'foo'. Below is what I have:

```
<?php function generateProject() {


$proj = $_GET['proj'];
$valid_proj = array("deadawesome", "chimaera", "manifesto");
if (!in_array($proj, $valid_proj)) {
}

echo '<div id="proj-wrapper">';
echo '<div id="proj">';
echo '<ul id="'.$proj.'">';

$imgs = glob("../images/portfolio/$proj/*.jpg");

foreach ($imgs as $picture) {
  // Get only the base filename
  $picture = basename($picture);

  // Then build the <li>
  echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="../images/portfolio/'.$proj.'/'.$picture.'">';
  echo '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="description">'.$projTitle.' <span class="slash">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>'.$projDesc.'</div>';

} ?>

    <?php
               generateProject();
    ?>
```

Would it be possible to make an array like this, and then find the one that matches 'foo' and give the following two values $projTitle and $projDesc?

```
$projTitles = array('foo' => 'FooTitle' => 'The description for Foo.',
                    'bar' => 'BarTitle' => 'The description for Bar.',
                    'presto' => 'PrestoTitle' => 'The description for Presto.'
                );
```

Comment: you want a multidimensional array i would guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an array of associative arrays:

```
$projects = array(
  array(
    'id' => 'foo', 
    'title' => 'FooTitle',
    'decription' => 'The description for Foo.'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 'bar',
    'title' => 'BarTitle',
    'description' => 'The description for Bar.'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 'presto',
    'title' => 'PrestoTitle',
    'description' => 'The description for Presto.'
  )
);
```

You can then loop through it and access the attributes of each array element like so:

```
foreach($projects as $project) {
  $id = $project['id'];
  $title = $project['title'];
  $description = $project['description'];

  echo "($id) $title - $description";
}
```

Comment: Awesome. How would I loop through and find the one that matched only $proj, and have that written into generateProject()? This code is only meant to pick out one of the arrays and build that out. Once another $proj is passed (ie 'foo' the first time, then 'bar') it will build out that one. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: in the `foreach` above, I would just add a test: `if ($project['id'] == $_GET['id']) { /* print everything out */ }`

Comment: Hm, trying to place it in, but it's not printing that part. Where do I add the `if` you mentioned? After `foreach` or the closing `}` of the whole statement?

Comment: GOT IT! The `if` you posted above said `$_GET['id']` when it should be `$_GET['proj']`. Thanks.

Comment: I would put the if inside the `foreach` in my answer and use it to escape the look using `break;`. The `$project` variable would then be available for printing outside the loop